# How to make a Subtraction with those values using alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code:

```
SELECT
    Coalesce(Sum(Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 'EE' Then M.VALOR End), 0) AS VALOR_EST_EMPENHO  ,
    Coalesce(Sum(Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 'LI' Then M.VALOR End), 0) AS VALOR_LIQ_BRUTO,
    Coalesce(Sum(Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 'EL' Then M.VALOR End), 0) AS VALOR_EST_LIQUIDACAO,
    Coalesce(Sum(Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO In ('PG', 'RT') Then M.VALOR End), 0) AS VALOR_PAG_BRUTO,
    Coalesce(Sum(Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 'EP' Then M.VALOR End), 0) AS VALOR_EST_PAGAMENTO,
    EMP_COD
FROM
    CTP_DESPESA_EMPENHADA_MOVIMENTACAO_VI M
GROUP BY
    M.EMP_COD
```

What I'm trying to do is to subtract them and getting the value, but they are using alias so when I do `VALOR_EST_EMPENHO - VALOR_LIQ_BRUTO` it gets me the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>   Invalid column name 'VALOR_EST_EMPENHO'

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: You need to repeat the expressions or use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: repeating the expressions using the "-" sign does not work too @GordonLinoff

Comment: `Coalesce(Sum(Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 'EE' Then M.VALOR End), 0) - Coalesce(Sum(Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 'LI' Then M.VALOR End), 0)` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. The CASE WHEN statement has an ELSE path. It is better to set that to 0 to avoid the COALESCE.
2. As suggested by others, you can repeat the COALESCE(SUM()) instructions to get the desired results. However for readability, I see where your are coming from.

   ```
   SELECT Sum(CALCULATED.VALOR_EST_EMPENHO) AS VALOR_EST_EMPENHO
    , Sum(CALCULATED.VALOR_LIQ_BRUTO) AS VALOR_LIQ_BRUTO
    , Sum(CALCULATED.VALOR_EST_LIQUIDACAO) AS VALOR_EST_LIQUIDACAO
    , Sum(CALCULATED.VALOR_PAG_BRUTO) AS VALOR_PAG_BRUTO
    , Sum(CALCULATED.VALOR_EST_PAGAMENTO) AS VALOR_EST_PAGAMENTO
    , Sum(CALCULATED.VALOR_EST_EMPENHO - CALCULATED.VALOR_LIQ_BRUTO) AS VALOR_X
    , M.EMP_COD
   FROM   CTP_DESPESA_EMPENHADA_MOVIMENTACAO_VI M
   CROSS APPLY(
     SELECT Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 'EE' Then M.VALOR ELSE 0 End AS VALOR_EST_EMPENHO
          , Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 'LI' Then M.VALOR ELSE 0 End AS VALOR_LIQ_BRUTO
          , Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 'EL' Then M.VALOR ELSE 0 End AS VALOR_EST_LIQUIDACAO
          , Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO In ('PG', 'RT') Then M.VALOR ELSE 0 End AS VALOR_PAG_BRUTO
          , Case When M.TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 'EP' Then M.VALOR ELSE 0 End AS VALOR_EST_PAGAMENTO
     ) CALCULATED
   GROUP BY
     M.EMP_COD
   ```

The inline table that results from the CROSS APPLY statement is calculated for each of the rows. In execution time, the query will expand the columns used from the inline table, so effectively, this will result in a query with more CASE WHEN statements.

I hope this helps.